# How to make excel link to same cell after insert

Tags: excel

I have a woorkbook with several sheets in it. There is 1 sheet that will be used as a presentation. The "presentation" sheet is linked to several "data sheets" which supply the hard data to it.

Now the cells in the presentation sheet are locked to data sheets. E.g. `$A$1`

In the presentation sheet I have several years in a row. 
I.e. `2015 2014 2013 2012`

Then I have a data sheet that provides the data through the linking. This data sheet has the corresponding design. `2015 2014 2013 2012`

Now, ONLY the latest year is linked. So in this case 2015 is linked from presentation sheet to the data sheet. The reason for this is because historical figures are hard coded and fixed. They will not be changed.

Now to my quetion:

I want to be able to INSERT a column in the DATA SHEET and have the linking from the PRESENTATION SHEET fixed.

As it is now (even with cells locked) when I insert a column in the data sheet, the locked cells in the presentation sheet follows that insertion and moves the cells one column to the right.

I'm not entirely sure on how to explain this matter but I hope you can understand me.

Note: the presentation sheet does not actually contain years, but is updated daily, but as example I chose years. I.e. Doing this manually once a year is not sustainable.

As of now I insert a column, add the new data for that day and then update the presentation sheet by the Replace command and replace the letters of that column back to the correct one.

Million of thanks to anyone who has a solution.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by linked. Are you saying there are cells on the presentation page that have formulas that get the values from other tabs/columns?

Comment: Linked as in Presentation sheet, cell A1 contains the function `='Data Sheet'!$B$5` from Data sheet. And then When I add a new column into the Data sheet, the linking follows with it, but I want it to stick with the same column all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing:

```
='Data Sheet'!$B$5
```

by:

```
=INDIRECT("'Data Sheet'!$B$"&5)
```

[INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) returns the reference specified by a text string and the text string does not adapt to Column insertion in the way the first formula above does.